# mysql running 3 queries gets blank page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, database

I am running the follow query using PHP and MySQL but if I just query 1 query it works but if I do 3 queries it does not work

Any idea why?

It seems like the while $ )) is causing the problem but tried so many ways and it just display nothing

```
 $boletas = mysqli_query($datacenter, "
    SELECT * FROM ventas 
    WHERE documento = 'boleta' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$facturas = mysqli_query($datacenter, "
    SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE documento = 'factura' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$notas = mysqli_query($datacenter, "
    SELECT * FROM ventas 
    WHERE documento = 'nota' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($revisar)){
    while($boleta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($boletas)) {
        while($factura = mysqli_fetch_assoc($facturas)) {?>


                <select class="selects" > 
                    <option value="3" data-price="
                    <?php
                    echo str_pad($boleta['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                    ?>">
                boleta</option>
                <option value="4" data-price="
                <?php
                echo str_pad($factura['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                ?>">factura</option>
                <option value="5" data-price="
                <?php
                echo str_pad($nota['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                ?>">nota de venta</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" class="inputs" 
            value="<?php
            echo str_pad($boleta['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            ?>">

            <?php
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

it just display a blank page using all 3 queries but if I use 1 query I do get the correct result
getting crazy with that

Comment: Have you checked your server error logs to see if it's throwing an error?

Comment: Missing something in `$boletas[] $boleta;`

Comment: It doesn't help changing your base code whilst asking a question, I would also say that the changes you have made will make your code less likely to work.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `mysql_fetch_assoc` uses the results from the last `mysqli_query` call.  If you wanted to fix your code, you would have to loop through the results of the first `mysqli_query` using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, store it in an array, loop through that array, THEN do the inner `mysqli_query`, and repeat.

```
<?php
$boletas_query = mysqli_query($datacenter, "
    SELECT * FROM ventas 
    WHERE documento = 'boleta' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

$boletas = array();

while ($boleta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($boletas)) {
    $boletas[] $boleta;
}


$facturas_query = mysqli_query($datacenter, "
    SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE documento = 'factura' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

$facturas = array();

while ($factura = mysqli_fetch_assoc($facturas)) {
    $facturas[] = $factura;
}


$notas_query = mysqli_query($datacenter, "
    SELECT * FROM ventas 
    WHERE documento = 'nota' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

$notas = array();


while ($nota = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notas)) {
    $notas[] = $nota;
}

foreach ($boletas as $boleta) {
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ($facturas as $factura) {
        ?>
        <?php
        foreach ($notas as $nota) {
            ?>


            <select class="selects" > 
                <option value="3" data-price="
                <?php
                echo str_pad($boleta['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                ?>">
            boleta</option>
            <option value="4" data-price="
            <?php
            echo str_pad($factura['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            ?>">factura</option>
            <option value="5" data-price="
            <?php
            echo str_pad($nota['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            ?>">nota de venta</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="inputs" 
        value="<?php
        echo str_pad($boleta['folio'] + 1, 15, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        ?>">

        <?php
    }
}
}
?>
```

However I do not recommend that as you can achieve what you want with a single query and it is far more efficient on the database.

Also, please indent and format your code when asking questions here.  I had to run it through a text editor to format it to be able to read it.

Comment: I added a solution.

Comment: I get the same blank page :(